# Unable to find method [someMethod] with [1] parameters

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a HIBERNATE DAOImpl with the following method, passing a variable as parameter..

```
  public List<Oportunidad> verParticipantes(String numeroOportunidad) throws DAOException {
    List<Oportunidad> lista = getHibernateTemplate().find("SELECT c.cliente FROM Oportunidad o ,OportunidadParticipante op,"
            + "Cliente c WHERE op.oportunidad=o.id and c.idCliente=op.cliente and o.numeroOportunidad=?",numeroOportunidad);
     return lista;
}
```

and the ServiceImpl

```
public List<Oportunidad> verParticipantes(String numeroOportunidad)throws DAOException {    
    return getOportunidadDao().verParticipantes(numeroOportunidad);
}
```

this interfaces by using, in both. 
These compile and run with junit doing a test. Goog, very good

---

The problem is, when I want to pass the parameter from a selectOneListboxt implemented a JSF primefaces

code ManagedBean:

```
  public String getVerParticipantes(String numeroOportunidad) throws DAOException{
    Oportunidad o = new Oportunidad();
    o.setNumeroOportunidad(numeroOportunidad);
      verParticipantes.addAll(getOportunidadService().verParticipantes(numeroOportunidad));
    return  "envioCotizacion.xhtml";
}
```

JSF code (. xhtml):

```
<p:selectOneListbox id="listaCliente" value="#{clienteMB.cliente}"  style="width:26%; height:90%;  position:absolute; top:10%; left:12%;">   
                    <f:selectItems value='#{oportunidadMB.verParticipantes("prueba")}'/> 
                    <!--  <f:param name="numeroOportunidad" value="prueba" />-->
                    <p:ajax id="numeroOportunidad" listener='#{oportunidadMB.verParticipantes("prueba")}'></p:ajax> 
                </p:selectOneListbox>
```

---

error screen:::::::::

```
javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Unable to find method [verParticipantes] with [1] parameters
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:444)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:161)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:173)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UISelectItems.getValue(UISelectItems.java:129)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.InputRenderer.getSelectItems(InputRenderer.java:55)
    at org.primefaces.component.selectonelistbox.SelectOneListboxRenderer.encodeMarkup(SelectOneListboxRenderer.java:49)
    at org.primefaces.component.selectonelistbox.SelectOneListboxRenderer.encodeEnd(SelectOneListboxRenderer.java:42)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:894)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:70)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:57)
    at org.primefaces.component.layout.LayoutUnitRenderer.encodeEnd(LayoutUnitRenderer.java:51)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:443)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
```

---

Help me plis...no longer to do with this error.

Answer (score 1):

```
<f:selectItems value='#{oportunidadMB.verParticipantes("prueba")}'...
```

should be

```
<f:selectItems value='#{oportunidadMB.getVerParticipantes("prueba")}'...
```

but 
getVerParticipantes should also return a list not a String !

```
public List<Oportunidad> verParticipantes(String numeroOportunidad)throws DAOException
```

is declared in the service but the manage oportunidadMB has only the method getVerParticipantes wich return a String instead of list so how can you call

```
value='#{oportunidadMB.verParticipantes("prueba")}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that bean name "oportunidadMB" is different from variable name jsf/camunda/etc context.

Comment: How do you know that this is the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Change method name `getVerParticipantes` to `verParticipantes`. The listener method does not need to be a getter.

Also you can't listener as an action so it should be return type of void e.g.

```
public void getVerParticipantes(String numeroOportunidad) throws DAOException{
    Oportunidad o = new Oportunidad();
    o.setNumeroOportunidad(numeroOportunidad);
      verParticipantes.addAll(getOportunidadService().verParticipantes(numeroOportunidad));
    //if you want to navigate then do here dynamically.
}
```